# Call the method using the parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How i can call method of controller using parameter in the url.

For example:  (URL can't be modify)

```
url #1: example.com/somecontroller?method=function1&param1="login"

url #2: example.com/somecontroller?method=function2&param1="login"&param2="pass"
```

In controller we have two methods:

```
public class SomeController:BaseController{

   public void function1(string param1)
    {
    //logic
    }

    public void function2(string param1, string param2)
    {
    //logic
    }
}
```

Have any idea??

Comment: You should be able to write custom routes to handle those URLs and invoke the appropriate action of the appropriate controller.  You'd just have to ensure that there was a valid route to catch invalid method names.

Comment: Can you write route example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify querystrings in routes, however you could create a route for just the controller, and have a generic actionresult that picks which actionresult to return based on your querystring values:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Distributor",
    url: "{controller}",
    defaults: new { action = "Distributor" }
);
```

And your new controller action:

```
    public ActionResult Distributor(string method)
    {

        switch (method)
        {
            case "MyMethod1":
                return MyMethod1();
            case "MyMethod2":
                return MyMethod2();
            default:
                return new HttpNotFoundResult();


        }
    }
```

This allows you to keep your url format of /{controller}?method={methodName}&param1=login

You'd have to handle your expected parameters for each method a little differently - for example you could do this:

```
    public ActionResult Distributor(string method)
    {

        switch (method)
        {
            case "MyMethod1":
                return MyMethod1(Request.QueryString["param1"]);
            case "MyMethod2":
                return MyMethod2(Request.QueryString["param1"], Request.QueryString["param2"]);
            default:
                return new HttpNotFoundResult();


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When a route is generated  your link should look like:

```
http://example.com/somecontroller/function1?param1="login"
```

where login is your param1 for function1 method.

Here’s an example of what the route might look like:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```